# can't chart what I want to chart with .hist() in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

simple question. hopefully it's really quite basic. I have a pandas dataframe named `firstperiod` and a column named `megaball`. The range of the values in `megaball` are from 1 to 25, and this line of code:

```
print firstperiod.megaball.value_counts().sort_index()
```

gives me this, which is what I want to see (the # of occurrences per possible value)

```
1     12
2      4
3      9
4      4
5      3
6      6
7      5
8      8
9      7
10    10
11     6
12     5
13     3
14     5
15     6
16     8
17    15
18     7
19     8
20     5
21     8
22     7
23     1
24    11
25     9
```

But when I go to to make a basic histogram of this, using

```
firstperiod.megaball.value_counts().sort_index().hist()
plt.show()
```

the chart isn't what i want at all (max y-value is 6 when it should be 15, x-axis only goes to 16). What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to do a histogram of those values, you just want to plot them as-is.  Try:

```
firstperiod.megaball.value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar')
```

You may have to fiddle with other plot options to get the plot to look exactly how you want.

Comment: thanks! could you explain why .hist() doesnt work in this case? Because afterall, I DO want a histogram of those values, no?

Comment: using "value_counts()" is already a sort of histogram.  if you remove it, you will be able to use the hist function.

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce: Basically what Dror Hilman said.  A histogram counts the values.  `value_counts` also counts the values.  If you do both, you count the values twice.  However, I find that in many cases for discrete data I want `value_counts` rather than `hist`, because `hist` bins the values, whereas `value_counts` actually counts each individual distinct value.

Comment: @BrenBarn @Dror Hilman gotcha. so why is it then that `firstperiod.megaball.hist()` produces an incorrect histogram that doesn't reflect what i get from value_counts? The x-axis is correct in ranging to 25, but the y-values are all incorrect.

Comment: even `firstperiod.megaball.value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='hist')` produces that same incorrect chart...

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce: Because `hist` *bins* the values, it does not necessarily display a separate bar for each individual value.

Comment: @BrenBarn: say i really wanted to make a histogram though. how would I go about that then with this data?

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce: You could use `hist`.  It *is* giving you a histogram.  It's just giving you a histogram with multiple values grouped into one bar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79605/discussion-between-spicyclubsauce-and-brenbarn).